# OnClick not working when rendering React button on a custom dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am a little bit lost hope someone with JS knowledge could help.

I am using this dialog: https://github.com/NBTSolutions/Leaflet.Dialog, on a leaflet map.

It is nothing much just opens a dialog on map when you call method like:

```
let dialog = L.control.dialog({
                size: [300, 300],
                anchor: [70, 0]
            });
dialog.setContent("<div id='camera-view-container'></div>")
dialog.addTo(that.mymap); // adds dialog on the map
```

You can see in the content I deliberately put a div with some ID because later I have code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<button onClick={()=>{alert("test")}}>Test</button>, document.getElementById('camera-view-container'));
```

**The thing is I can see the button on the dialog**, however, the click handler doesn't work?

What can be causing this problem?
In which part of code should I look for solution?

Thanks

---

Very strangely if I:

1. Put the button inside a component and
2. Inside component render method I put:

   `<button className="buttons" ref={(save) => this.save = save}>Save</button>`
3. And finally in componentDidMount of that component I do:

   `this.save.addEventListener("click", () => {alert("test")});`

Then it works.

**Why?**

Comment: does it log any error in console?

Comment: @AnshulSahni No nothing on the console

Comment: can you please create a react sandbox for this will be easier to debug, the current snippet does not clarify anything

Comment: @AnshulSahni I have updated my question

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<button onClick={()=>{alert("test")}}>Test</button>, document.getElementById('camera-view-container'));` This line is working actually. Can you please create a demo in stackblitz?

Comment: I too created a sandbox for you with similar case https://codesandbox.io/s/2xxz3635k0, and it is working

Comment: @AnshulSahni That line works separately when only used inside React. But it doesn't work the way I use it (e.g. in Leaflet and that dialog as I showed).

Comment: @AnshulSahni I am sorry at the moment I can't create the fiddle but I think I gave all the needed info. Just create any JS project with leaflet use that dialog and you should be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is with event binding. Because that button is not an actual DOM element until you see it in leaflet dialog.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the problem

When you put the button in leaflet dialog as content it is not in DOM until the dialog gets displayed. So you cannot target it until it appears (or loaded fully).

There are some builtin functions of how leaflet dialog behaviors when you show it

You must have set map element somewhere like -

```
  var map = L.map('map').setView([42.8962176,-78.9247419], 12);
```

So you set the events when dialog is opened

```
 map.on('dialog:opened', function(e){ console.log(e.target); //your content element });
```

You get the target as content. This is the way to go. You can try calling the method inside `:opened` callback.

For all instances of leaflet you can go in the view source

http://nbtsolutions.github.io/Leaflet.Dialog/

Here you will get set of methods

```
map.on('dialog:opened', function(e){ console.log("dialog opened event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:closed', function(e){ console.log("dialog closed event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:destroyed', function(e){ console.log("dialog destroyed event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:locked', function(e){ console.log("dialog locked event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:unlocked', function(e){ console.log("dialog unlocked event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:frozen', function(e){ console.log("dialog frozen event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:unfrozen', function(e){ console.log("dialog unfrozen event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:updated', function(e){ console.log("dialog updated event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:resizestart', function(e){ console.log("dialog resizestart event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:resizing', function(e){ console.log("dialog resizing event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:resizeend', function(e){ console.log("dialog resizeend event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:movestart', function(e){ console.log("dialog movestart event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:moving', function(e){ console.log("dialog moving event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:moveend', function(e){ console.log("dialog moveend event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:closehidden', function(e){ console.log("dialog closehidden event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:closeshown', function(e){ console.log("dialog closeshown event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:resizehidden', function(e){ console.log("dialog resizehidden event fired."); });
map.on('dialog:resizeshown', function(e){ console.log("dialog resizeshown event fired."); });
```

Comment: I added this: `that.mymap.on('dialog:opened', function(e){ 
                ReactDOM.render(<button onClick={()=>{alert("test")}}>Test</button>, document.getElementById('camera-view-container'));

            });` but  now the button is not shown at all